# Characters missing in console

Tags: windows, console, code-blocks

I am working on implementation of an SIC-XE assembler with my friends. Those guys are using windows and codeblocks while I am using ubuntu 12.04 and codeblocks(both using version (10.05).
[This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1321428/) is a piece of code used to print values from an [input](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1321440/) file. It is working fine in windows but when I use it on linux my console doesnt print the first four charcter. This is my [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1321445/). Can anyone tell me the reason for this.

Comment: It might be a text encoding issue. Try using dos2unix to convert the input file. You can also try to create a new file in unix with the same input and save it as plain text. If that doesn't work, your program is not portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a text-encoding issue between Windows & Ubuntu. There is a utility that converts file encoding to unix/dos style called dos2unix. (The complementary tools is unix2dos).

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
dos2unix filename.txt
```

It will convert line endings from Windows to Unix style.

Alternatively, you can just create a new file, using gedit, and paste the contents. Gedit would save it with the correct line endings. (CR, instead of CRLF)

Comment: both things worked. Thnks.