# newer to coding not sure if this is the correct way to manage variables for a project anyone have a second to help me?

Tags: command-line, server, scripts, log, database

Here is a log (I've only included the matching lines there is a lot of other stuff in the real log)

```
/home/steam/pavlovserver/Pavlov/Saved/Logs/Pavlov-backup-2021.07.07-08.51.08.log:[2021.07.06-17.30.30:443][570]PavlovLog: TicketValidation succeed for: 76561198149279501 Saltheili
/home/steam/pavlovserver/Pavlov/Saved/Logs/Pavlov-backup-2021.07.07-08.51.08.log:[2021.07.06-20.56.45:053][555]PavlovLog: TicketValidation succeed for: 76561198041336824 Lumenero
/home/steam/pavlovserver/Pavlov/Saved/Logs/Pavlov-backup-2021.07.07-08.51.08.log:[2021.07.06-22.22.12:299][270]PavlovLog: TicketValidation succeed for: 76561198345598849 GusRemington
/home/steam/pavlovserver/Pavlov/Saved/Logs/Pavlov-backup-2021.07.07-08.51.08.log:[2021.07.07-02.03.19:386][ 55]PavlovLog: TicketValidation succeed for: 76561198302880912 Snitchhy
/home/steam/pavlovserver/Pavlov/Saved/Logs/Pavlov-backup-2021.07.07-08.51.08.log:[2021.07.07-02.40.29:749][786]PavlovLog: TicketValidation succeed for: 76561198291769546 Jupiter
/home/steam/pavlovserver/Pavlov/Saved/Logs/Pavlov-backup-2021.07.07-08.51.08.log:[2021.07.07-03.38.14:208][307]PavlovLog: TicketValidation succeed for: 76561198220506681 Fedora
```

i am trying to pull info and set to variables using this

```
id=($(grep  'TicketValidation'  ~/pavlovserver/Pavlov/Saved/Logs/* | cut -b 153-170))
date=($(grep  'TicketValidation'  ~/pavlovserver/Pavlov/Saved/Logs/* | cut -b 58-67))
name=($(grep  'TicketValidation'  ~/pavlovserver/Pavlov/Saved/Logs/* | cut -b 171-270)
```

here is the format i want to get

```
$date PlayerName; $name PlayersID; $id
```

but i am having problems getting it to be on 1 line i am trying to send to array do i need to add `[*]` somewhere?

if i run `echo ${id[@]}`:

```
76561198149279501 76561198041336824 76561198345598849 76561198302880912 76561198291769546 76561198220506681
```

and that looks right but on name im getting only this
`echo ${name[@]}`:

```
 Fedorarygton
```

if i run `$ grep  **'TicketValidation'  ~/pavlovserver/Pavlov/Saved/Logs/* | cut -b 171-270`      (the grep from the $name var)

i get

```
Saltheili
Lumenero
GusRemington
Snitchhy
Jupiter
Fedora
```

Ideas?

Comment: We can't tell you if your code will work if you don't show us your code. Please [edit] your question and i) add your code, ii) add an example input and iii) the output you expect from that input.

Comment: updated i changed it around a bit trying to find a way to work but this is where im at currently

Comment: I would look into `awk` for the whole thing.

Comment: like just restart using only awk ?

Comment: You seem to have CRLF line-endings. Fix it using `dos2unix`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/210183/characters-missing-in-console/210420#210420